# how to force linker to use shared library instead of static library?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, shared-libraries

This is a quote from Linux programming book:

---

> `% gcc -o app app.o -L. –ltest`

Suppose that both `libtest.a` and `libtest.so` are available.Then the linker must
choose one of the libraries and not the other.The linker searches each directory (first
those specified with `-L` options, and then those in the standard directories).When the
linker finds a directory that contains either `libtest.a` or `libtest.so`, the linker stops
search directories. If only one of the two variants is present in the directory, the linker
chooses that variant. Otherwise, the linker chooses the shared library version, unless
you explicitly instruct it otherwise.You can use the `-static` option to demand static
archives. For example, the following line will use the `libtest.a` archive, even if the
`libtest.so` shared library is also available:

`% gcc -static -o app app.o -L. –ltest`

---

Since if the linker encounters the directory that contains `libtest.a` it stops search and uses that static library, how to force the linker to search only for shared library, and not for static?

`% gcc -o app app.o -L. libtest.so` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use `-l` option in its form `-l:filename` if your linker supports it (older versions of `ld` didn't)

```
gcc -o app app.o -L. -l:libtest.so
```

Other option is to use the filename directly without `-l` and `-L`

```
gcc -o app app.o /path/to/library/libtest.so
```

Comment: Note: This use of `-l` is undocumented.  It will include the full path to the library in the executable, which means the library can never be moved from its current location.

Comment: @KevinPanko `-l` option is documented in `man ld`, https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld - I cannot easily test it but according to the doc : If namespec is of the form `:filename`, `ld` will search the library path for a file called `filename`. Like I mentioned, older versions of `ld` don't support this option.

Comment: I was checking the documentation for `gcc` here: [Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: Well, it doesn't mention any version - neither of gcc nor ld. Using `man ld`  will show you the documentation relevant for your version of the linker.

Comment: `-l:filename` is also useful when we need to use a static library

Answer (score -1):

from the man  :

> -shared-libgcc
>    -static-libgcc
>              On systems that provide libgcc as a shared library, these options
>              force the use of either the shared or static version respectively.
>              If no shared version of libgcc was built when the compiler was
>              configured, these options have no effect.

good luck

Comment: isn't that just for libgcc? it doesn't solve the problem for other libraries

Comment: yup,that's my fault. you can write the libname.so to link with it as kobac said,thanks for the correction