# Issues to build project with boost-thread

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, boost-thread

I'm trying to build my project using boost-thread, but I'm getting the following error:

```
 /usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: ./boost/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.a(thread.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC ./boost/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

 make[1]: * * * [objdir/rel64/xerel64.so] Error 1

 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xe'

 make: * * * [build64] Error 2
```

I did already built libboost_thread with `address-model=64_32 architecture=combined` and with `address-model=64 architecture=combined`, and didn't work.

Here's how I build it:

```
g++ -Wl,-Bsymbolic -L./lib -L./cryptopp -shared -L./mysql/lib
-L./boost/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib -shared -m64 -s -o objdir/rel64/xerel64.so
objdir/rel64/./Callbacks.o  objdir/rel64/./CAnnounceBox.o  objdir/rel64/./CClans.o
objdir/rel64/./CCommands.o  objdir/rel64/./CCore.o  objdir/rel64/./CFunctions.o
objdir/rel64/./CIRC.o  objdir/rel64/./CPlayer.o  objdir/rel64/./CSettings.o
objdir/rel64/./CVehicle.o  objdir/rel64/./Main.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lmysqlclient64
-lcrypto64  -lboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58 -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -lpthread -lrt
```

Comment: I guess you're trying to build a shared library. However the compiler is complaining that the code from libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.a (the library it has found for -lboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58) is not re-locatable. If you have a libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.so, make sure it is used (see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422493/how-to-force-linker-to-use-shared-library-instead-of-static-library)), Otherwise, not 100% sure, but you might want to try to leave the static library out of the shared library you're building. It will need to be added when linking the full program.

Comment: "recompile with -fPIC" - did you try adding that to the compiler flags?

Comment: @jsantander, so should I use: -l:libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.so ?

Comment: Have you checked if the *.so library exists? To tell the truth, I've never used personally that syntax...

Comment: It does:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 273466 Apr 22 18:26 libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     39 Apr 22 18:26 libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.so -> libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.so.1.58.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 175686 Apr 22 18:26 libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.so.1.58.0`

Comment: Good news! I found the solution, but wasn't what I wanted, however did it work.
I just dynamically linked libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58.so with `-Bdynamic` and moved libboost_thread-gcc48-mt-1_58 and libboost_system-gcc48-mt-1_58 files to `/usr/lib`and link them with `ln` command. I hope that helps who got that problem too.