# compiling against libstdc++.so.5 is not finding symbols @GLIBCPP_3.2

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, libstdc++

I am building an application which makes use of a third party library which requires libstdc++.so.5. Until recently I was compiling my application with libstdc++.so.6 which worked fine, however it had some portability issues.

Therefore I decided installing g++ version 3.3.4 in order to be capable of compiling my application with libstdc++.so.5. However now I cannot compile my application at all. Neither with my old g++ nor with the 3.3.4 Version of it... Building the application reports the following error message:

```
/opt/ExPansion/lib/libexpansion.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_istream(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)@GLIBCPP_3.2'
```

**EDIT:**
Interesting might also be the output of the following commands:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5 | grep 'LIB'    
GLIBCPP_3.2
GLIBCPP_3.2.1
GLIBCPP_3.2.2
GLIBCPP_3.2.3
GLIBCPP_3.2.4
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW
```

The only thing that makes me wonder is the following:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
nm: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5: no symbols
```

Is that "normal"? Is it possible that my lib is not containing the needed symbols? I downloaded this lib through:

```
yum install compat-libstdc++-33
```

..so it shouldn't be causing any problems..

From my understanding @GLIBCPP_3.2 is provided by my libstdc++.so.5. So what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Maybe this lib needs a newer version of the libstdc++. Take a look if that version is listed here: "find / -name "libstdc++.so.5" 2> /dev/null -exec strings {} \; | grep

'GLIBCPP".

Comment: Hi,  the output of your command is identical to the following output: $ strings /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.5 | grep 'LIB' I updated my question with the output of this command. What does that mean for us? That I need a newer version of the libstdc++.so.5 library?

Comment: I guess so, or an older version of the expansion lib or the expansion lib  recompiled with the old gcc and old c++ lib.

Comment: Hmm.. Got myself libstdc++.so.5.0.7 (I had 5.0.6) which contains the GLIBCPP_3.2 string.. The problem still persists..

Comment: Does it point to the correct lib? Try "ldd -v libextension.so"

Comment: Oh wait, you are trying to link and not run it. Then just ignore my last post sorry.

Comment: But still if the lib itself has dependencies need to resolve it could be possible it points to the wrong libstdc++

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help so far. The lib should be pointing to the correct libstdc++.. I updated my question with my findings. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @fassi Found the solution! Thanks for your invaluable help!

Comment: Great! What was the problem?

Comment: I posted an answer to the question. I still have to find out what exactly causes the problem. However, you were right. Apparently the linker could not find the libstdc++.so.5 library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what causes my linker not finding the lib on its own...
The following question helped me however find a "workaround" to my problem: [how to force linker to use shared library instead of static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422493/how-to-force-linker-to-use-shared-library-instead-of-static-library)

Simply forcing my linker to link against the library helped..

```
gcc -o app app.o {other libs} /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
```